# More hints for what tags are preferred

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently under tags edit box there is only this info:
*Combine multiple words into single-words, space to separate up to 5 tags (voting bug)*

I think it should have more hints to prevent creation of new, improper tags all over again.

Comment: Something like forbidding use of already consolidated tags (vc++, msvc++ or visual-c - choose one and forbid other two)

Answer (score 4):

Even just a few examples (and anti-examples) would be good. The retag thread is full of such ;-p

Answer (score 4):

A message dissuading people from creating new tags would be a good idea, perhaps "Try to use appropriate existing tags before creating new ones"

Also perhaps mention of how to pluralise tags, say `exception` or `exceptions`?