# Why does it say "(voting bug)" under Tags input (..or "Better example tags")

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Err, why does it say `... (voting bug)` under the Tags input, on the Ask a Question page?

Comment: @Frenzy please don't leave such things in the post, it's pointless.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll take note. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marc Gravell said, they are examples...

Maybe it should say it should explicitly say it is an example like `(eg: voting bugs)` just to be clear.

Comment: And perhaps (as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/more-hints-for-what-tags-are-preferred) it should include something about the dashed-tags ;-p

Comment: I agree.  It should definitely have at least an example of a dashed tag.

Comment: "As stated" - it does mention they are examples anywhere, but your second paragraph is right - it should be!

Comment: Oh, I meant as stated by Marc Gravell.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it selects a few at random (or has been hard-coded with appropriate examples); on SO it is <kbd>python</kbd> <kbd>c#</kbd> <kbd>ruby</kbd>, and on SF <kbd>secure</kbd> <kbd>ssh</kbd> <kbd>raid</kbd>.

On MSO, we've been talking about <kbd>voting</kbd> and <kbd>bug</kbd>s, apparently ;-p

Comment: Err.. That makes sense, I don't think I ever noticed the example tags before - I only really read the message because of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/more-hints-for-what-tags-are-preferred and when I did "voting bug" seemed utterly random..

Comment: It does sound like an error message that has made it to the UI, doesn't it ;-p