# Change 'how to tag' and/or move it for visibility

Tags: feature-request, tags

I must've come across 1000s of questions that are terribly tagged. Some don't even include a programming language anywhere in the post or tag. These questions are very often overlooked (as I see from looking at old questions), since the tags used often have very few followers or are applicable to a different domain or simply because people cannot tell what programming language the question is applicable to (which there are also a lot of comments about).

So it might be a good idea to make the 'how to tag' more visible / change it so it makes specific reference to programming language and/or API.

**My suggestion** is that, between 'Tags' and the box where you fill in tags (or just below) (so it's very difficult to miss), there be a message like: (with the current 'how to tag' remaining as is in its current position)

"Remember to include tags for the programming language and specific API used (if applicable)."

I want to say force one of a subset of tags to appear, but this can't really work, since there are too many options. I know tag hierarchy has been declined, but something similar may work if a tag hierarchy is implemented, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so/163915#163915).

Related - People use tags like `table` or `alignment` way too often, and these generally don't appear to be helpful in my opinion. I wonder whether removing these would motivate people to use better tags. All the tags used incorrectly in a certain context can't really be removed for various reasons (though some probably should be). A point can be added to 'how to tag', but it probably requires a bit of space to explain and I'm not sure this will really help.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/more-hints-for-what-tags-are-preferred

Comment: @LanceRoberts Though that didn't have any resolution (unless it was pre-'how to tag') and this has a specific suggestion.